# Detect availablility of <sdkddkver.h> and <winapifamily.h> from Developer Command prompt?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, sdk, header-files, nmake

We have a [Nmake-based makefile](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/cryptest.nmake#) to help with testing under Visual Studio, including Visual Studio .Net/2002 through Visual Studio 2015. The makefile [includes the following](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/cryptest.nmake#L63):

```
CXXFLAGS = /nologo /W4 /wd4511 /D_MBCS /Zi /TP /GR /EHsc /MD /FI sdkddkver.h /FI winapifamily.h
LDFLAGS = /nologo /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
ARFLAGS = /nologo
LDLIBS =
```

It works great under later Visual Studios, like 2015 Developer Command prompt, because `<sdkddkver.h>` and `<winapifamily.h>` are always available from the SDKs. Testing under Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7, or Visual Studio 2005 on Windows Vista, does not go so well:

```
> nmake /f cryptest.nmake

cl.exe /nologo /D_MBCS /Zi /TP /GR /EHsc /MD /FI sdkddkver.h /FI winapifamily.h /Yc"pch.h" /Fp"pch.pch" /c pch.cpp
pch.cpp
pch.cpp : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winapifamily.h': No such
 file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\
VC\BIN\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

We would like to guard the force includes based on the availability of `<sdkddkver.h>` and `<winapifamily.h>`. I checked the environment using `set` and Nmake's environment with `nmake -p`, but nothing is jumping out at me.

How can we detect when `<sdkddkver.h>` and `<winapifamily.h>` are available from a Visual Studio Developer command prompt?

---

This is kind of the step *before* [Platform defined macros for windows store app](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3965645c-978c-4148-b32c-1853f7fd22b3/platform-defined-macros-for-windows-store-app?forum=winappswithnativecode). I think the following are similar or related questions, but they assume the files we are trying to detect are already present:

- [How to detect WP8 at compilation time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25573752)
- [Detect Windows Kit 8.0 and Windows Kit 8.1 SDKs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36961152)

---

Here are two attempts which I know *don't* work when testing under VS2015:

```
# Both WindowsSdkDir and WindowsSdkVersion are defined in environment
!IF "$(WindowsSdkDir)" != "" || "$(WindowsSdkVersion)" != ""
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXFLAGS) /FI sdkddkver.h
!ENDIF
```

And:

```
!IF EXIST(sdkddkver.h)
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXFLAGS) /FI sdkddkver.h
!ENDIF
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I can provide a partial answer for `<sdkddkver.h>`. I don't have a solution for `<winapifamily.h>` that instills a lot of confidence.

> Here are two attempts which I know don't work when testing under
>   VS2015:
>
> ```
> # Both WindowsSdkDir and WindowsSdkVersion are defined in environment
> !IF "$(WindowsSdkDir)" != "" || "$(WindowsSdkVersion)" != ""
> CXXFLAGS = $(CXXFLAGS) /FI sdkddkver.h
> !ENDIF
> ```

It appears environmental variables are transformed to uppercase when made available as a Nmake macro, so the following worked as expected:

```
!IF "$(WINDOWSSDKDIR)" != "" || "$(WINDOWSSDKLIBVERSION)" != ""
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXFLAGS) /FI sdkddkver.h
!ENDIF
```

---

Here's the partial solution for `<winapifamily.h>`. Its OK for Windows Phone 8 and Windows 10. But its got a dead zone around Windows 8 with Visual Studio and SDKs installed. The dead zone is it fails to determine that `<winapifamily.h>` is available:

```
!IF "$(WINDOWSPHONEKITDIR)" != "" || "$(UNIVERSALCRTSDKDIR)" != "" || "$(UCRTVERSION)" != ""
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXFLAGS) /FI winapifamily.h
!ENDIF
```